# Git commit message not working with atom 1.21.1

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am trying to add commit message using atom and setting it as my default editor using 
`git config --global core.editor "atom"` but as soon as I enter git commit it opens atom and gives the message `aborting commit due to empty commit message.`
I also tried adding `--wait`. After searching for a while I found this was the problem in previous versions but was fixed later but I don't know then why I am facing this problem

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: windows 10 64bit

Comment: What if to use other editor?

Comment: i tried using notepad and that worked, its only giving me error while using atom

Comment: Is your Atom editor configured to autosave the file? Maybe it saves the file when Atom starts and that's why you've got this message. But that'll be strange, normally, a lock is applied.

Comment: No it's not configured to automatically save the file

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait --foreground"
```

There was an old bug ([`atom/atom` issue 3074](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3074#issuecomment-140218334)) in 2015, but it should work now (Q4 2017).

See also [`atom/atom` issue 12027](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12027#issuecomment-228183962).